# treeMerge in swi-prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to build a predicate treeMerge(A,B,C) that returns true if C is the result of merging the two trees A and B. Any suggestions on how I can implement this? I have a rough idea, I am thinking of merging the root, then first child then second and so on, but I am fairly new to prolog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to get the list of the nodes inside a tree then add each nodes in the other tree. I've developed a predicate `merge/3` which merges the two tree as input in a third tree (insert all the nodes of the first tree into the second). A tree is represented as `t(Node,Left,Right)`. Here is the code:

```
getNodes(nil,[]).
getNodes(t(E,L,R),[E|S]) :- 
    append(SL,SR,S), 
    getNodes(L,SL), 
    getNodes(R,SR),!.

insert(Node,nil,t(Node,nil,nil)).
insert(Node,t(El,Left,Right),t(El,L,R)):-
    (Node > El ->  
        insert(Node,Right,R),
        L = Left
    ; insert(Node,Left,L),
        R = Right).

insertNodesList([],T,T).
insertNodesList([H|T],Tree,M):-
    insert(H,Tree,T1),
    insertNodesList(T,T1,M).

merge(T1,T2,Merged):-
    getNodes(T1,LNodesT1),
    insertNodesList(LNodesT1,T2,Merged).
```

Query:

```
?-merge(t(3,t(2,t(1,nil,nil),nil),t(4,nil,t(7,nil,t(5,nil,nil)))),t(3,t(2,nil,nil),t(4,nil,t(7,nil,t(5,nil,nil)))),T).
T = t(3, t(2, t(2, t(1, nil, nil), nil), t(3, nil, nil)), t(4, t(4, nil, nil), t(7, t(7, t(5, nil, nil), nil), t(5, nil, nil))))
```